# Way to get google place_id inside my Android app

Tags: android, google-places

I have an Android app.
And I need to get google place_id in my app.

For now I haven't found smooth way to get things done.

Currently my solution includes 3 steps:

1. get current coordinates
2. get address using coordinates from previous step
3. get google place_id using address from previous step

This approach works, but I'm sure there got to be better way.

Please let me know how to solve this task in a proper manner.

Comment: i think this is infact the proper approach.

Comment: You cannot get a place without the address and you cannot get an address without the co-ordinates. So, this is the proper way. What other way you have in your mind?

Comment: @PrerakSola, 

I would like to have possibility to get current google place_id without step1 and step2 from my question, just like I can get current coordinates without any extra steps.